# How to unalias a minus?

Tags: bash, bash-alias

My morning coffee hadn't reached my brain yet when I forgot the quotes in:

```
alias grep="grep --color=always"
```

so instead I typed:

```
alias grep=grep --color=always
```

leaving me with:

```
--color=always
grep=grep
```

in my aliases.

When I try to cleanup the --color=always using `unalias --color` I get:

```
bash: unalias: --: invalid option
unalias: usage: unalias [-a] name [name ...]
```

I tried escaping, quoting and begging, but I can not figure out how to make the commando unalias cleanup the mess.

(I know a restart will do the trick but surely there must be another way)

Comment: Ha ha, now I got it stuck in mine also, working on it EDIT: Looks like choroba's answer worked for me

Comment: Kind of reminds me of the old `echo > \\?\c:\windows\x.`, or that time I `rm -rf * ~` by accident.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can avoid POSIX compliant systems interpreting dashes in commands by adding `--` before any arguments.

```
mtak@frisbee:~$ alias grep=grep --color=always
mtak@frisbee:~$ alias | grep color
alias --color='always'

mtak@frisbee:~$ unalias -- --color
mtak@frisbee:~$ alias | grep color
mtak@frisbee:~$
```

This also works with other utilities, let's say you have a file named `-bla`. If you try to remove it with `rm` you will get the following error:

```
mtak@frisbee:~$ ls -- -bla
-bla
mtak@frisbee:~$ rm -bla
rm: invalid option -- 'b'
Try 'rm ./-bla' to remove the file '-bla'.
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
```

By using `--` before the filename, you will remove the file:

```
mtak@frisbee:~$ rm -- -bla
mtak@frisbee:~$ ls -- -bla
ls: cannot access '-bla': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Though it's worth noting that for files, an equally valid method is to use a path to the file that avoids this; so you can use `ls ./-bla` and `rm ./-bla` (or specify the full paths, whatever's easier in your case). Obviously this doesn't work for aliases though!

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html Guideline 10

Answer (score 91):

Just use the same trick you used to set the alias

```
unalias whatever --color
```

Comment: works indeed, +1 but the other solution is a bit cleaner :)

Comment: Indeed, of course :-)

Comment: `unalias unalias --color`

Answer (score 3):

#### Fast solution

To fix **both** the wrong aliases you may simply run

```
unalias grep --color
```

---

#### Understanding what's happened

You give the wrong command `alias grep=grep --color=always` without `"..."`.

- **You set two aliases** `--color` and `grep`; indeed you can read it on the left side of your output (all at the left of the `=` is a aliased command):

  ```
  --color=always
  grep=grep
  ```

  so you need to unset both.
- **Why this happened?**
  The `...` in the synoptic of alias means that is possible to do multiple assignation in one line:

  > alias: alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]

  In the output of `help alias` you can read the synoptic but from `man bash` you can read that is possible in the same line even to list and assign at the same time:

  > When arguments are supplied, **an alias  is  defined for  each  name whose value is given.**  A trailing space in  value causes the next word to be checked for alias substitution when the alias is expanded.  **For each name in the argument list for which no value is supplied, the name and value of the alias is printed...**
- **You have problems to unset the first one `--color` alone**.
  This because **it is interpreted as options** for `alias` by your shell; to avoid this you need communicate to your `bash` shell that what is following it is not an option.
- The ***Holy Grail* of Linux: `man`**, in this case `man bash` that is a coffer filled with treasures useful in situation like this.
  You can read from `man bash`:

  > --         A  --  signals the end of options and disables further 
  >   option processing.  **Any arguments after the -- are treated as filenames
  >   and arguments**.  An argument of - is equivalent to --.

  As reported in other answer the POSIX way is to use the special character combination `--`.

  ```
  unalias -- --color
  ```
- But **why `unalias grep --color` is working?** I mean without using `--`?
  As it worked for `alias` even for `unalias` it is possible to give more than one name in one time (again the `[...]`).

  ```
  unalias: unalias [-a] name [name ...]
  ```

  I can give only my guess: a good programming habit is to write the reading and writing routines at the same time, below the same logic. So it has to be for the option parsing routines of `alias` and `unalias`.

  That this works you can see even from this command (from a shell opened for this purpose) that will not erase all your aliases:

  ```
  unalias whatever -a
  ```

#### Final remark

In the BUGS section of `man bash` among the few things reported you may read `:-)`

> Aliases are confusing in some uses.